# Can Chrome's context menu show all defined search engines?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to know whether there exists such a Chrome extension that when I select some words and right click on it, **the context menu shows all DEFINED search engines in Manage Search Engines of Chrome's Settings** which are available in the omnibox. Then I can choose one of the defined search engine to search the selected keywords.

I've checked some extensions, including [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-search/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga), [Simple = Select + Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-select-%20-search/aagminaekdpcfimcbhknlgjmpnnnmooo?hl=en-US), and [Multi-Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afmdpmddiokpdknaeofdnlclbpgehhce). They unfortunately don't suit my requirements because **they ask me to define search engines AGAIN and cannot retrieve the ones defined in Chrome!** We, programmers, do not like repeatting ourselves, do we?

Comment: Why isn't the list of defined search engines enough? You can customize this list without using extensions.

Comment: @harrymc The defined search engines now can only be used in the address bar. I want them to appear in right-click menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome settings are not exposed via any web APIs, and is not meant to be customized. The [current list of published Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html) does not include `chrome://settings`. Google Chrome's philosophy leans towards a simple, efficient browsing experience for the end users, as opposed to flexibility and extensibility.

Therefore, there is no possibility of creating an extension with a context menu that can utilize all **Managed Search Engines**.

The closest that one can programmatically manipulate Chrome settings is via the *proposed* [Settings page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/settings_pages). Even then, the proposal is targeted to *custom* Chrome settings instead of existing settings.

Comment: Do you get the bounty? I didn't come here days before because of business. If you don't get it, I feel very sorry about it.

Comment: @LoveRight Didn't get any bounty, but I am glad that there is closure for this question. The biggest satisfaction I experience is from successfully helping another person to solve their problem; upvotes, accepted answers and bounties are bonuses :)